# Showing Nested Model Partials on user Index/profile page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, nested-attributes

I an struggling with the syntax of the controller for nested models. There are many other questions out there but i am not having any luck and i have reached my 2 day struggling threshold, so its time to ask!

I have 3 Models, User, Farm, Product. - User has_many Farms, Farm has_many Products.

On the user show page i display a list of farm/s created by the user in a partial...

```
#users_controller
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id]) 
    @farms = @user.farms   
  end

#show.html.erb
 <% if @user.farms.any? %>
   <center><h4>My Farms(<%= @user.farms.count %>)</h4></center>
   <hr>
<%= render @farms %>
```

This works as expected.

What i would like to do is display all the products of the farm, within the _farm partial, as a list. However I dont know what to add to the controller? Adding

```
@products = Product.find(params[:id])
```

obviously displays all products, not just one made by that farm. So how to i create the controller code and/or the partial code to only show the products created by that particular farm?

I was thinking along the lines of...

```
@products = Product.find(params[:farm_id])
```

but it does not work and seems to simple!

I obviously need to pass a key somewhere to the partial within the partial, but i have no idea how to do it!

Any Help will be massively appreciated...its driving me nuts!

Many thanks, Alex

EDIT ::

```
#product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :farm_id, :name, :ammount, :price, :category, :pic, :longitude, 
  :latitude, :image

  belongs_to :farm

 mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader


#farm.rb
class Farm < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :content, :name, :user_id, :description, :street_name, :bldg_name, :region, :post_code, 
                        :province, :contact_number, :swap, :organic, :deliver, :image, :products_attributes


  belongs_to :user
  has_many :products
 acts_as_followable
  validates :user_id, presence: true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :products
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader


#user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  mount_uploader :avatar, ImageUploader
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :confirmable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :name, :region, 
    :description, :avatar, :street_name, :bldg_name, :post_code, :province, :contact_number, :avatar, 
    :avatar_cache, :remove_avatar, :products_attributes, :product

  # attr_accessible :title, :body

  acts_as_follower

  has_many :farms
  has_many :swaps
  has_many :products, :through => :farms

  # validates_presence_of   :image
  # validates_integrity_of  :image
  # validates_processing_of :image

  has_private_messages
```

EDIT 2 ::

```
#_products.html.erb

<hr>
<div class="row-fluid">

      <div class="span3"> <%= image_tag product.image_url(:thumb) %> </div>  

      <div class="span5"> 
         <h2><%= product.name %></h2>
         <table>
<tr>
<td><strong>Ammount Available ::</strong></td>
<td><center><%= product.ammount %></center></td>
<td><strong>Kilos</strong></td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Price/Kilo ::</strong></td>
<td><center><%= product.price %></center></td>
<td><strong>Euros</strong></td>
</tr></table>
      </div>     
      <br><br><br>
      <div class="span3">   
<%= link_to "View Product", product, class: "btn btn-small btn-secondary"  %>
<% if correct_user?(@user) %>
  <%= link_to "delete", product, class: "btn btn-small btn-secondary", method: :delete, confirm: "You sure?" %><% end %>


      </div>
```

-

```
#_farm.html.erb
<div class="<%= cycle("even", "odd") %>">
<div class="container">

<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span2">
    <%= image_tag farm.image_url %>
  </div>

  <div class="span2">
    <%= farm.name %>
  </div>

  <div class="span4">
    <span><%=  "   Location  ::  " %><%= farm.user.region %></span><br>
    <span><%=  "   Can it be delivered  ::  " %><%= farm.deliver ? 'No' : 'Yes' %></span><br>
    <span><%=  "   Is it Organic  ::  " %><%= farm.organic ? 'Yes' : 'No'  %></span><br>
    <span class="timestamp">Listed on <%= farm.created_at.strftime("%d %b. %Y") %> </span>


  </div>
  <div class="span4">
<br>
<br>
<br>

<%= link_to 'Sell A Product', new_farm_product_path(farm), class: "btn btn-small btn-secondary" %> 
<%= link_to 'Edit Grow Spot', farm, class: "btn btn-small btn-secondary" %> 
  </div>         
 </div><!-- end container -->  
</div>

<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span2"></div>
  <div class="span8">

<% for product in farm.products do %>
  <%= render :partial => "product", :product => product %>
<% end %>

  </div>
  <div class="span2"></div>
```

Comment: show your models code, if everything is right there you should write farm.products and have all the products for each farm

Comment: thanks @rmagnum2002. Have listed Model code. How would you render farm.products as a partial? I have not tried putting it in a block to iterate over all products, although maybe worth a try. Looking to renter the partial because of the HTML prettyness!, rather than just a list of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `<%= render @farms %>` in a view means you must have a partial called `_farm.html.erb` in `app/views/farms`

in that partial you can use `farm` variable:

```
<% for product in farm.products do %>
  <%= product.name %>
  <%= product.price %>
  .... 
<% end %>
```

no need to add something in controller.

**update**

```
<% for product in farm.products do %>
  <%= render :partial => "product", :locals => { :product => product } %>
<% end %>
```

in `app/views/farms/_product.html.erb`

```
<div class="zzz">
   <div><%= product.price %></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh, Genius! Let me give it a shot!

Comment: Thanks @rmagnum2002 That works, and is a step closer, but is giving just a list as you would expect. Can i make it look nicer but getting some HTML in there? Like a partial?

Comment: Hey @rmagum2002, That is exactally what i was looking for, but it does not work! First off it did not find the template, but i moved it to /views/users/ and was fine. But now its giving 'undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass'. The code works, but when its in a partial it does not! Will add the partial code to the question incase there is a fault there.

Comment: I have updated the code.. rendering a partial with locals was the part  I hated the most. I am never sure how and when to use it :)

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials  **3.4.4 Passing Local Variables** tells you how to send variables to partials, but they use the case with a instance variable `@zone` and not `zone` so I am not sure it will work for you. In my app in a case like yours I just quit using partials.

Comment: That worked a Charm! Thank you so much! I am in my 3rd day hunting this solution so you a legend!

Comment: :D glad that worked for you.. everybody was in this kind of situation when starting something new